# Finite set "pod" placement

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry if I'm getting some of the terminology wrong. I have a math brain for everyday stuff but I haven't taken anything past calculus in 10th grade 15 years ago.

I'm trying to set up a tournament with some friends for a game we all play.  What I'm looking for is a way to divide the 16 of us into 2 pods of 8 for 8 rounds, so that we play in the same pod as everyone the same number of times.

The first realization I had was that for 8 rounds, since you don't count yourself, you basically have 56 other people in your pod (7x8) across the 8 rounds and 64 people (8x8) not in your pod. That means you should be in the pod with everyone 4 times and in a different pod with everyone 4 times. Except, you're going to have 4 people you see 3 times and miss 5 times.

I then decided a way to help visualize and organize was to assign a card to each person. Ace, King, Queen, Jack of Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, and Spades. Hearts and Diamonds only end up together 3 times, same with Spades and Clubs. Everyone else is 4 together and 4 apart. Had a lot of fun on the excel spreadsheet trying to find a pattern that would work to achieve this goal and felt like I got 95% of the way and hit a wall, so here I am.

If there is a way to order the results such that after each round exactly 4 of the 8 players in each pod switch and the other 4 stay put in order to maximize perceived diversity, that would be a nice bonus as well. Same if nobody was ever in the same pod with someone more than 3 times in a row.

Just a solution would be nice, but if there are any articles, books, or videos that would help me actually learn this as an "advanced layman", that would be phenomenal!

Thanks!

Comment: While this isn't exactly what you're looking for, the idea of [combinatorial designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design) are pretty similar. You might want to take a look at some of the constructions you find there.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant, haven't checked: http://www.tournamentdesign.org/